# Xcode Different Resources For Different Targets

Tags: xcode, resources, reference, target, custom-build-step

I am developing an iPhone app and there will be a Full as well as a Lite version of that app. In order get both bundles from the same source code and Xcode project I added another target to the Xcode project.

Now, I want to have the Lite target copy only a subset of the resource files to the bundle. But, Xcode won't simply let me delete individual files from the "Copy Files to Bundle" build step, since I imported all my resources as folder references. I need this in order to maintain a directory structure in the resources directory.

How do I solve this problem? Any suggestions or ideas are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 7):

In the left-hand panel of Xcode, right-click on the "Groups & Files" bar at the top. Check "Target Membership".

Now you'll see a tick against every file that should be included in your current build target. Untick the ones you don't want, switch to your other target, and repeat.

Comment: XCode 4 users use this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5300785/adding-files-to-seperate-targets-in-xcode-4

Answer (score 4):

Instead of manipulating the "Copy Bundle Resources" step of your target, you can right-click resource files or groups (folders), choose "Get Info," and selectively leave stuff out of your Lite build under the Targets tabs of the info window for the file(s) you selected.  Doing this on a group (folder) recurses the changes, so using resource groups (folders) is a nice easy way to make separate resources collections for separate builds.