# Linker error when compiling in Xcode

Tags: xcode, linker, linker-errors

I am getting this error when I am compiling a program in Xcode.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MyDatabase", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Gallery_CollectionViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have forgotten to add the source file that implements the class `MyDatabase` to the Xcode target and consequently it hasn't been compiled and linked with the binary.

Comment: so what should I supposed to do now ?

Comment: @AshishPatil You need to add the file that implements `MyDatabase` to the binary target.  See this SO answer for how to do that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5300785/adding-files-to-seperate-targets-in-xcode-4

Comment: m gettin following error now, what is this ?                    0x12c3d35:  movl   16(%edx), %edx
Thread 1 : EXE_BAD_ACCESS

Comment: @AshishPatil That's a different issue.  Ask a new question about that, and don't forget the symbolic stacktrace (i.e. type `bt` in the debugger console and post the output) and include the code around the lines that crashed.