# Parse for iOS: Errors when trying to run the app

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I've been working with the Parse SDK and I followed the quickstep guide. When I try to run, I get these 8 errors. Any ideas as to why? It looks like something to do with the Facebook part of Parse which I'm not using.

```
 Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
"_FBTokenInformationTokenKey", referenced from:
  -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy accessToken] in Parse(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
  -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy setAccessToken:] in Parse(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
 "_FBTokenInformationExpirationDateKey", referenced from:
  -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy cacheTokenInformation:] in     Parse(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
  -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy expirationDate] in Parse(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
  -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy setExpirationDate:] in Parse(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
 "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy", referenced from:
  _OBJC_METACLASS_$_PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy in Parse(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy", referenced from:
  _OBJC_CLASS_$_PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy in Parse(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
"_FBTokenInformationUserFBIDKey", referenced from:
  -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy facebookId] in Parse(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
  -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy setFacebookId:] in Parse(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBRequest", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in Parse(PFFacebookAuthenticationProvider.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSession", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in Parse(PFFacebookAuthenticationProvider.o)
 ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: It looks like you need to add the .m files to target: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5300901/620197

Comment: sounds like if if either of those 2 flags -ObjC and -all_load are present, the Facebook SDK must be present/installed... or you can remove those flags if you don't really need them, but i think restKit needs them, hence i need them. https://parse.com/questions/undefined-symbols-for-my-architecture-updating-parse

Comment: just add bolt.framework and facebook.framework with -objc flag.its work for me.

Comment: ld: framework not found Metal for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 137, accepted):

This is some sort of bug associated with the Parse iOS 1.1.33 release as multiple people are seeing the same errors- myself included.

There are a couple of workarounds-

If you're not using a library which requires the -ObjC linker flag, you can remove -ObjC from your project:

Build Settings > Other Linker Flags > remove -ObjC

or if you are using a library which requires that flag, you can add the Facebook SDK.

Both options will eliminate the errors. Hopefully they fix this as I have no need for the Facebook SDK in my app.

Follow the discussion here:

https://parse.com/questions/cocoapods-incompatibility

Comment: Removing -ObjC didn't fix it for me. dbquarrel's response below did though.

Comment: i removed the -all_load linker flag and that fixed it for me, so you can update the answer to also include that flag C:

Comment: In Other linker flags I had '-all_load' before , from 'pod install' it suggested to set 'other linker flag' to '$(inherited)', it worked without any issue.

Comment: Can you please point where to find and how to add facebook SDK to Xcode 6.2 (iOS 8)? I have https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios where after installing Facebook.pkg I cannot find `FacebookSDK.framework` file and has other unnecessary files.

Comment: There is a problem if you remove the -ObjC linker switch. The libCordova.a library specifies some categories on NSString which will not get loaded if -ObjC is removed.

A work around is to remove libCordova.a from the linked frameworks and add this to the Other Linker Flags build setting:

-force_load $(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/libCordova.a

Comment: I am getting this error ld: framework not found Metal for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 102):

Here's a potentially simpler workaround than downloading, compiling, and installing the FB kit which is kind of large and cumbersome. Note that, of course, you won't be able to use any of the FB type functionality in Parse and you will run into severe issues if you trigger any of the Parse code that is expecting to use these dummy symbols. But, if you stay away from them you'll be OK I think. So...

1. Create an object in your application called FBMissingSymbols
2. Delete the .h you won't need it
3. Put this in the .m :

```js
NSString *FBTokenInformationExpirationDateKey = @"";
NSString *FBTokenInformationTokenKey = @"";
NSString *FBTokenInformationUserFBIDKey = @"";
@interface FBAppCall:NSObject
@end
@implementation FBAppCall
@end
@interface FBRequest:NSObject
@end
@implementation FBRequest
@end
@interface FBSession:NSObject
@end
@implementation FBSession
@end
@interface FBSessionTokenCaching:NSObject
@end
@implementation FBSessionTokenCaching
@end
@interface FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy:NSObject
@end
@implementation FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy
@end
```

Comment: This is magical solution.. if you do not want FB integration in your app go for it.

Answer (score 26):

You have to delete the old `ParseFacebookUtils.framework` and keep the new `ParseFacebookUtilsV4.framework` to get it working.

Comment: HEY YOU SCROLLING THIS THREAD, THIS IS THE CORRECT ANSWER! /\

Comment: This is what fixed it for me! None of the dev comments on Parse's websites or other answers here worked... +9000 if I could!

Comment: Easy and perfect. Thanks!

Comment: Yep…this is it. Why is this old busted library still shipped with the Parse SDK?? This shouldn't be so complex.

Answer (score 23):

I loved dbquarrel's answer, but it doesn't work anymore because it is lacking some new social classes.

So do the same thing, but instead, add this:

```
NSString *FBTokenInformationExpirationDateKey = @"";
NSString *FBTokenInformationTokenKey = @"";
NSString *FBTokenInformationUserFBIDKey = @"";
NSString *SLServiceTypeTwitter = @"";
NSString *ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter = @"";
@interface FBAppCall:NSObject
@end
@implementation FBAppCall
@end
@interface FBRequest:NSObject
@end
@implementation FBRequest
@end
@interface FBSession:NSObject
@end
@implementation FBSession
@end
@interface FBSessionTokenCaching:NSObject
@end
@implementation FBSessionTokenCaching
@end
@interface FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy:NSObject
@end
@implementation FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy
@end
@interface ACAccountStore:NSObject
@end
@implementation ACAccountStore
@end
@interface SLRequest:NSObject
@end
@implementation SLRequest
@end
@interface SLComposeViewController:NSObject
@end
@implementation SLComposeViewController
@end
```

Comment: Create an object in your application called `FBMissingSymbols`, Delete the .h (because you dont need it), then put the above in `FBMissingSymbols.m`

Comment: Doesn't this new `.m` file need `#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>` included at the top?

Answer (score 10):

Check and make sure that you do not have two versions of the "ParseFacebookUtils" framework added there is:

ParseFacebookUtilsV4
and
ParseFacebookUtils

Once I removed ParseFacebookUtils, and kept ParseFacebookUtilsV4 it worked fine.

Comment: This was exactly the problem. Once removed, all 9 errors went away! Thanks

Answer (score 7):

My Solution will definitely work and you can use -ObjC in other linker flags.

1. Add "Social.framework" , "Account.framework"
2. Add "FacebookSDK.framework"

Cheers....now it works..... and no need of removing -ObjC.

Comment: This is really simple & great answer. But only thing is in my case I didn't added the Facebook.framework & still it built the app without error. But anyways, +1 for simple solution.

Comment: For me it was just adding the "Social.framework" , "Account.framework". Thanks, works like a charm :)

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you might need to add the 'Accounts.Framework' and/or the 'Social.Framework'.

Answer (score 2):

A complementary to the answer by @blueHula . 
Parse has removed Facebook SDK from its framework, meaning that from some certain version (1.1.33 maybe) integrating parse.framework should be accompanied by integrating FB SDK independently.

Please refer to this link [using the parse ios sdk without including the facebook sdk](https://www.parse.com/questions/using-the-parse-ios-sdk-without-including-the-facebook-sdk)

The key point is to use `-force_load $(SRCROOT)/path/libname.a` to link with necessary third-party libraries, rather than using `-all_load` and `-ObjC`

Answer (score 1):

It is a linker error...  You are not including a needed framework in your project which you are referencing in one of you included header files.

So, for example, if you an have an include in your code:

```
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
```

It probably requires a supporting framework, and you have to include it in your app.  Did you include the `parse.framework` from within Xcode?

[image: Xcode Frameworks]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same use and and the only third party I had was the PayPal SDK. After removing -ObjC everything built fine. (always make a backup of you project before changing settings)

Answer (score 1):

it's 2015 and I just had the same error.  Unfortunately, none of the above answers worked for me.  But this did:

**Target > Build Phases > Link Binary With Libraries** 
**then add libstdc++.6.dylib**

This solved the problem for me.

Comment: seems to fix part of the issues

Answer (score 0):

There are many frameworks that needs to set -ObjC flag as Other linked flag, whereas Parse do not allow you to proceed if you do so. To deal with this you can do one of following things. I have shown example of Google Maps SDK that needs -ObjC flag, but due to Parse in the same project I can not use it directly:

**Solution 1 - Using force_load Flag**

Instead of setting -ObjC flag as Other linked flag, use force_load flag to load particular framework or library.

```
-force_load $(SRCROOT)/GoogleMaps.framework/Versions/A/GoogleMaps
```

**Solution 2 - Using Facebook SDK**

Just Add Facebook SDK as a separate framework, this will allow you to use -ObjC flag. Also make sure you have added `Accounts.framework` and `Social.framework`. If you have added Bolt.framework and using Parse blank project then to deal with duplicate symbol remove `Bolt.framwork`.
If still it have few errors then remove Accounts and Social framework and Add it again (This will be the case if you have used Parse default blank project).

Answer (score -1):

I was bothered this issue for many days. I used cocoapods to manage all of third SDK.

Here is how I resolved this issue. Go to pod project and set the item "build architecture only" to NO.

Rebuild pod project and then link errors is gone! help this can help someone who is using cocoapods.[image]

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. I solved by downloading the previous version (1.1.32) from here:

https://parse.com/downloads/ios/parse-library/1.1.32

(In my case I needed the -ObjC flag)

Edit: It seems that version doesn't work with 64 bit architectures.

Answer (score -1):

This can be removed from the project-file located in
 `<projectname>/cordova/<projectname>/platforms/ios/<projectname>.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj` and

Search the file for `-ObjC`, there are multiple locations. It looks like this:

```
OTHER_LDFLAGS = (
    "-weak_framework",
    CoreFoundation,
    "-weak_framework",
    UIKit,
    "-weak_framework",
    AVFoundation,
    "-weak_framework",
    CoreMedia,
    "-weak-lSystem",
    "-force_load",
    "\"$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/libCordova.a\"",
    "-ObjC",
);
```

Answer (score -1):

Install cocoaPods and add this to your Podfile:

```
pod 'Facebook-iOS-SDK'
pod 'Parse'
pod 'ParseFacebookUtils'
```