# problems adding Google Maps to my app

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, linker-errors

i wanna use Google Maps with my app. i downloaded the SDK and read the Starting Guide and applied it to my app. i added the libraries needed (double-checked them, or maybe a dozen), created my API key and added it to my app, and then added the code to add a map view. when i run the app i received the errors:

```
Unknown class GMSMapView in Interface Builder file.

+[GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:longitude:zoom:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x32d670
```

so to solve the first error: i checked that the storyboard views are well connected and my views had the right classes connected to. however, it didn't work. i search over here about similar problems and most of them were like "try to product>clean to the app then rerun". i tried it and didn't work even deleting the app from the simulator didn't help.

to solve the second problem, i also searched for it and most of the solutions were to add the *-ObjC* at the *Other Linker Flags* in the "Target" and not in the Project. so i did that plus changed the Architecture to armv7 (as also stated by Google). however, i received a bunch of 8 errors concerning the *Match-O Type*

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_FBTokenInformationExpirationDateKey", referenced from:
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy cacheTokenInformation:] in Parse(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy expirationDate] in Parse(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy setExpirationDate:] in Parse(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
  "_FBTokenInformationTokenKey", referenced from:
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy accessToken] in Parse(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy setAccessToken:] in Parse(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
  "_FBTokenInformationUserFBIDKey", referenced from:
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy facebookId] in Parse(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy setFacebookId:] in Parse(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBRequest", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFFacebookAuthenticationProvider.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSession", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Parse(PFFacebookAuthenticationProvider.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy in Parse(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy in Parse(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

i wanna note that i'm also using Parse data backup in my app, and the errors are somehow pointing to them and i don't know why! so after that i tried to change the Architecture to armv7 and the other Linker Flags to -ObjC in the Project and not the target (as Google advised). The match-o type errors disappeared but the errors i originally stated are still there.

Please, somebody help me out with this!! i want it to work so bad and i've tried all iterations of solutions. i also downloaded a sample code uploaded by google demoing how to add google maps using storyboarding (which works). i imitated it also it didn't help. Btw they added the -ObjC in target and it's working!! so it Parse doing the problem? i can't exclude it from my app, i'm heavily using it to back up the users data.

Answer (score 1):

What are you seeing are issues related to the Facebook SDK and not Google Maps... Which can be solved with this: [Parse for iOS: Errors when trying to run the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15457136/parse-for-ios-errors-when-trying-to-run-the-app)