# Adding Tapku Library to iOS Project - Linker Errors

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform, linker-errors, tapku

I'm building a calendar application and am trying to add the Tapku library to my app. I've followed the steps here: "https://github.com/devinross/tapkulibrary/wiki/Adding-Tapku-to-Your-Project-in-XCode-4". My project builds until the last step. When I add "-ObjC" to other linker  flags I get errors when building.

I've included a screenshot with an error saying that the flag is invalid along with the linker errors.

https://f.cloud.github.com/assets/5856011/2443796/032501d0-ae40-11e3-9b4b-9f29aa46bb81.png

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you add the search paths?

Comment: @MackC Yeah, I added "./tapku/src" to the header search path. The tapku folder is located in the same folder as the .xcodeproj file.

Comment: I think it is this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15457136/parse-for-ios-errors-when-trying-to-run-the-app I'll post an update later in the day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that my project was using both Parse and Tapku. After following the instructions here: [Parse for iOS: Errors when trying to run the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15457136/parse-for-ios-errors-when-trying-to-run-the-app) I was able to get it working.