# Parse SDK Facebook error

Tags: facebook, parse-platform

here is our problem;

/Users/NAME_HERE/Documents/FacebookSDK/FBAudienceNetwork/Samples/MediationAdapters/Admob/FBAdMobCustomEventBanner.h:19:9: 'GADCustomEventBanner.h' file not found

We used this [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15457136/parse-for-ios-errors-when-trying-to-run-the-app/18626232#18626232)

to fix the missing .m file, but now we don't know how to fix the missing .h file?

Comment: Please use the tag parse.com for questions about parse.com. "parsing" is not related.

Comment: Don't reference the .h file