# Missing Facebook SDK for Parse using Swift

Tags: swift, parse-platform, facebook-sdk-3.0

This question is a lot like this one: [Parse for iOS: Errors when trying to run the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15457136/parse-for-ios-errors-when-trying-to-run-the-app) except that I am using Swift in XCode Beta 4.

Essentially, when using the Parse library my app build fails, noting that I need resources from the FacebookSDK. Downloading the SDK works, but as this question on Parse's website: https://parse.com/questions/using-the-parse-ios-sdk-without-including-the-facebook-sdk notes, it adds over 1MB that I don't use.

The former question lists "Build Settings > Other Linker Flags > remove -ObjC" as a solution, but I can't figure out how to do that in this XCode version. Any help/ other solutions?

(FYI, Another solution on that page suggests creating a FBMissingSymbols.m file, but that gives me other errors because of trying to use Objective C)

Comment: This post will likely have what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002369/how-to-call-objective-c-code-from-swift/24005242#24005242

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very simple solution for this is to use the [CocoaPods](http://www.cocoapods.org) dependency manager. If you need help setting it up, let me know. If you'd rather not, I can gladly help you get Parse set up, as I've been using it with Swift.