# Push notifications - which way is the best?

Tags: cordova, parse-platform

I have an phonegap angularjs ionicframework app that I need to add push notifications to. The datastore makes use of `parse.com` which has push notifications built in, (kinda, not much support for js sdk).
To fill the gaps left by js sdk, I am making use of [phonegap-parse-plugin](https://github.com/benjie/phonegap-parse-plugin)
This appears to work, but i am confused as to how it works when I never followed any of the instructions here: [android-push-notifications](https://parse.com/tutorials/android-push-notifications)
and [ios-push-notifications](https://parse.com/tutorials/ios-push-notifications)

Can someone shed some light? Am I missing something by not following the instructions on the two pages above?

Answer (score 1):

This is a good plugin for Push notification. You can easily integrate push notification with this. But this is not working for iOS with Phonegap Build. If you are working Xcode you can easily integrate. I used this plugin 3-4 months back for both iOS and Android. In iOS I got an Error when I tried to run the app. I am not sure if they have corrected it or not. Still this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15457136/parse-for-ios-errors-when-trying-to-run-the-app) will help you.