# How to Add FacebookSDK iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, facebook, parse-platform

I am facing the issue posted in this [Parse for iOS: Errors when trying to run the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15457136/parse-for-ios-errors-when-trying-to-run-the-app) and the solution mentioned is to add `FacebookSDK.framework` to the Xcode project and this should resolve the issue. 
After installing [Facebook SDK for IOS](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios) pkg.

But I cannot find `FacebookSDK.framework` file in `Documents/FacebookSDK` dir.

Can any one please guide me in this?

**Note:** Using Xcode 6.2 and iOS 8 (latest)

**update 1**

I have the following frameworks in settings

[image]

And the `Documents/FacebookSDK` looks like below. Which lib is to be included in Xcode? and how?

[image]

Comment: I guess this is the solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/15465369/2099097, and they are not saying to add FacebookSDK.framework

Comment: the link is same as in the question and if you read it carefully it says `if you are using a library which requires that flag, you can add the Facebook SDK. `. and I have a lib that uses `-ObjC` hence my question ...

Comment: yes it asks you to add Facebook SDK but there is nothing specifically mentioned about **Facebook.Framework** file, you can add your Facebook SDK in the search paths

Answer (score 1):

If you've downloaded the latest Facebook SDK version (> v4), the framework has been splitted into several kit. Instead of FacebookSDK.framework, include the FBSDKCoreKit and FBSDKLoginKit frameworks at least.

Answer (score 0):

After successful download of Facebook SDK, you may go to Home from **Finder -> GO -> Home Menu**, click over it. and Goto **Documents** Folder, you will find out **FacebookSDK** folder.

You may miss to set **/Users/userName/Documents/FacebookSDK** in **Framework Search Path**. **userName** is user Login Username.

**Update 1**

From **April 2**, Facebook has updated **new version**, with separated framework for several functions.

```
FBSDKCoreKit.framework required for all other framework as basics.

FBSDKLoginKit.framework is required for Login and session management.

FBSDKShareKit.framework for Sharing Post, images and all.
```

You can Drag and Drop this framework from your folder to **Link Binary to Library section** (Drag from second image screen window and drop it to first image window.)

Answer (score 0):

[image]Make sure you have added the `libsqlite3.dylib`framework and also make sure `Bolts.framework` come s in top of the hierarchy.

Comment: I do have the lib already available in frameworks. please have a look at the screenshots I added.

Comment: Please add Bolts.framework in your framework files as well. Also keep it right in the top

Comment: can you please tell me how did you find `FacebookSDK.framework` in your linkers? and also from where did you add?

Comment: The FacebookSDK folder you downloaded, doesn't it have the `FacebookSDK` framework

Comment: nope.. I have checked and downloaded multiple times.. see picture 2 I have added screenshot of what `Documents/FacebookSDK` folder has

Comment: I am not sure. I download this a week back. [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios) . This had the required

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75168/discussion-between-inceptor361-and-adam-young).