# Compile Error using Parse and Facebook Frameworks in Xcode 6.3 (Swift)

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform, frameworks, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm trying to integrate Parse and Facebook's SDK with my app using Xcode 6.3 and am getting these errors when attempting to build:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSDKAppEvents", referenced from:
      __TMaCSo14FBSDKAppEvents in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSDKApplicationDelegate", referenced from:
      __TMaCSo24FBSDKApplicationDelegate in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PFAnalytics", referenced from:
      __TMaCSo11PFAnalytics in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PFFacebookUtils", referenced from:
      __TMaCSo15PFFacebookUtils in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Parse", referenced from:
      __TMaCSo5Parse in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I don't know what this means, but I've tried many other solutions, such as cleaning, deleting the Derived Data folder, checking all of my frameworks, and I still can't solve the problem. If anyone has any idea how to fix this I would be very grateful. Thank you for your time.

**Edit**
This is the Bridging-Header.h that I'm using:

```
#import <AFNetworking.h>
#import <BDBOAuth1RequestOperationManager.h>
#import <NSDictionary+BDBOAuth1Manager.h>
#import <UIImageView+AFNetworking.h>
#import <UIScrollView+SVInfiniteScrolling.h>
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
#import <FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.h>
#import <FBSDKShareKit/FBSDKShareKit.h>
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
#import <ParseCrashReporting/ParseCrashReporting.h>
#import <ParseFacebookUtilsV4/PFFacebookUtils.h>
#import <Bolts/Bolts.h>
```

This is the AppDelegate.swift file:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
import Parse
import FBSDKCoreKit
import FBSDKLoginKit
import Bolts

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarStyle(UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent, animated: true)

    // Type casting in swift is "as Type", you'll need to unwrap optionals however.
    let tabBarController = self.window!.rootViewController as! UITabBarController
    let tabBar = tabBarController.tabBar as UITabBar

    // I prefer to use 0 based labels since the array is 0 based
    let tabBarItem0 = tabBar.items![0] as! UITabBarItem
    let tabBarItem1 = tabBar.items![1] as! UITabBarItem
    let tabBarItem2 = tabBar.items![2] as! UITabBarItem

    // The UIColor method you are using is an initializer in swift
    tabBar.tintColor = UIColor(red: 62.0/255.0, green: 191.0/255.0, blue: 180.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

    // UIImage also has an initializer for your situation in swift
    tabBarItem0.selectedImage = UIImage(named: "Discover TabBar Select.pdf")
    tabBarItem1.selectedImage = UIImage(named: "Me TabBar Select.pdf")
    tabBarItem2.selectedImage = UIImage(named: "Settings TabBar Select.pdf")

    //Facebook SDK Setup
    FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance()
    Parse.setApplicationId("HxjVTJZ2rZA6qFBl0Xaji9z12HYQmTFPIXhVcfPp", clientKey:"8FJT7KHSmDPZi1AtpFS1GvTw39qevvB0JuimwWdS")

    if let launchOptions = launchOptions {
        PFFacebookUtils.initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions(launchOptions)
    } else {
        PFFacebookUtils.initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions([NSObject:AnyObject]())
    }

    // [Optional] Power your app with Local Datastore. For more info, go to
    // https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#localdatastore/iOS
    Parse.enableLocalDatastore()

    // [Optional] Track statistics around application opens.
    PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions)

    return true
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the      application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    FBSDKAppEvents.activateApp()
}
```

I dragged the latest Parse and Facebook SDK Frameworks into my project and added the required additional Frameworks (including the libsqlite3.dylib and libz.dylib) through the "Link Binary with Libraries" tab under the "Build Phases" section

I hope this additional information is useful.

Comment: Could you provide us with the code you're trying to build?

Comment: @Armin did you fix this problem?

Comment: @Lücks I've still been trying to fix the problem, and I think I made some progress, but it's still not working. I added the Parse frameworks through the "Link Binary Libraries" tab and I think that fixed a lot of the problems, but now I think the issue is in the bridging header. I deleted the old bridging header and made a new one but it's saying "failed to import bridging header" and certain framworks (specifically the facebook related ones) are getting an error stating something like "could not build module 'FBSDKCoreKit'"

Comment: @Armin we can open a bug on Parse or post a question on their forum about this problem.

Comment: Have you fixed this? Facebook recently released 4.1.0 of their SDK which fixes Swift/Obj-C compile errors, does your build compile with the latest version?

Comment: I decided to just try making a brand new project and start from scratch, and I managed to get it working past the previous issue. However, I ran into another large error, which was solved using the FBMissingSymbols.m method I found in another Stackoverflow question

Comment: @armin- i also got same issue. did you figure out ? please help me

Comment: @RahulRawat Unfortunately I couldn't find anything, but I recreated everything in a new project and it worked out for some reason. I think the error came from the Bridging Header being disconnected somehow. If you're still getting an error try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15457136/parse-for-ios-errors-when-trying-to-run-the-app

Comment: @armin- not problem. i fixed that please try below answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After updating Parse to version 1.7.4, this problem fixed itself. Hopefully this helps other people who faced the same problem as me!

Answer (score 9):

I also faced same problem. In My mine, Facebook sdk 4.1. These were my steps:-

1) Go to Build Settings

2) Type **other linker flags**. and since i am using objective C. so i clicked on it and add two new values. first is **-ObjC** and second is **$(inherited)**. After adding these two values your other linker flags would be show as **-ObjC -ObjC -|"Pods-......** something like as. i am using cocapods.

3) now type "Allow Non-modular Includes in Framework Modules" and use YES value.

4) then type "Enable Modules (C and Objective-C) and it should be YES.

and clean and build your project. If it still not work for you then please check your Link Binary Libraries. In My Mine, these are frameworks.

```
Accounts.framework
AddressBook.framework
Foundation.framework
CFNetwork.framework
GoolgeMaps.Framework
Social.framework
CoreData.framework
QuartzCore.framework
Security.framework
CoreLocation.framework
CoreGraphics.framework
UIKit.framework
```

Please try it Thanks

Comment: I tried following your instructions and got 45 more errors

Comment: WOW! It Worked. I Looked a LOOONG time for the Answer to this one. You sHould get like 100+ Votes :-)

Answer (score 0):

What fixed my problem was to add the Facebook Frameworks to Linked Frameworks and Libraries. Note, this wasn't included in the Facebook Login documentation.