# Swift - Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 after adding Parse

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have a project with facebook auth provided by sdk downloaded from developers.facebook.com. Everything worked fine until I added Parse libraries. 
Now I have linker error with following text

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_FBTokenInformationExpirationDateKey", referenced from:
  -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy cacheTokenInformation:] in    ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
  -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy expirationDate] in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
  -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy setExpirationDate:] in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
"_FBTokenInformationTokenKey", referenced from:
  -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy accessToken] in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
  -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy setAccessToken:] in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
"_FBTokenInformationUserFBIDKey", referenced from:
  -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy facebookId] in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
  -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy setFacebookId:] in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBAppCall", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookAuthenticationProvider.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBRequest", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookAuthenticationProvider.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSession", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookAuthenticationProvider.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy", referenced from:
  _OBJC_CLASS_$_PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_SLComposeViewController", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in ParseTwitterUtils(PF_Twitter.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_SLRequest", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in ParseTwitterUtils(PF_Twitter.o)
"_OBJC_METACLASS_$_FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy", referenced from:
  _OBJC_METACLASS_$_PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
"_SLServiceTypeTwitter", referenced from:
  -[PF_Twitter _getAccessTokenForReverseAuthAsync:localTwitterAccount:] in ParseTwitterUtils(PF_Twitter.o)
  -[PF_Twitter _getLocalTwitterAccountAsync] in ParseTwitterUtils(PF_Twitter.o)
 "std::string::find_first_of(char const*, unsigned long, unsigned long) const", referenced from:
  MacStringUtilsPFC_::IntegerValueAtIndex(std::string&, unsigned int) in ParseCrashReporting(string_utilities.o)
"std::string::find_first_not_of(char const*, unsigned long, unsigned long) const", referenced from:
  MacStringUtilsPFC_::IntegerValueAtIndex(std::string&, unsigned int) in ParseCrashReporting(string_utilities.o)
 "std::string::substr(unsigned long, unsigned long) const", referenced from:
  MacStringUtilsPFC_::IntegerValueAtIndex(std::string&, unsigned int) in ParseCrashReporting(string_utilities.o)
 "std::string::_Rep::_M_destroy(std::allocator<char> const&)", referenced from:
  BreakpadPFC_::HandleUncaughtException(NSException*) in ParseCrashReporting(Breakpad.o)
  BreakpadPFC_::Initialize(NSDictionary*) in ParseCrashReporting(Breakpad.o)
  BreakpadPFC_::GenerateReport(NSDictionary*) in ParseCrashReporting(Breakpad.o)
  google_breakpadPFC_::ExceptionHandler::ExceptionHandler(std::string const&, bool (*)(void*), bool (*)(char const*, char const*, void*, bool), void*, bool, char const*) in ParseCrashReporting(exception_handler.o)
  google_breakpadPFC_::ExceptionHandler::ExceptionHandler(bool (*)(void*, int, int, int, unsigned int), void*, bool) in ParseCrashReporting(exception_handler.o)
  google_breakpadPFC_::ExceptionHandler::~ExceptionHandler() in ParseCrashReporting(exception_handler.o)
  google_breakpadPFC_::ExceptionHandler::UpdateNextID() in ParseCrashReporting(exception_handler.o)
  ...
"std::string::_Rep::_S_empty_rep_storage", referenced from:
  BreakpadPFC_::HandleUncaughtException(NSException*) in ParseCrashReporting(Breakpad.o)
  BreakpadPFC_::Initialize(NSDictionary*) in ParseCrashReporting(Breakpad.o)
  BreakpadPFC_::GenerateReport(NSDictionary*) in ParseCrashReporting(Breakpad.o)
  google_breakpadPFC_::ExceptionHandler::ExceptionHandler(std::string const&, bool (*)(void*), bool (*)(char const*, char const*, void*, bool), void*, bool, char const*) in ParseCrashReporting(exception_handler.o)
  google_breakpadPFC_::ExceptionHandler::ExceptionHandler(bool (*)(void*, int, int, int, unsigned int), void*, bool) in ParseCrashReporting(exception_handler.o)
  google_breakpadPFC_::ExceptionHandler::~ExceptionHandler() in ParseCrashReporting(exception_handler.o)
  google_breakpadPFC_::ExceptionHandler::UpdateNextID() in ParseCrashReporting(exception_handler.o)
  ...
"std::string::append(char const*, unsigned long)", referenced from:
  google_breakpadPFC_::MinidumpGenerator::UniqueNameInDirectory(std::string const&, std::string*) in ParseCrashReporting(minidump_generator.o)
"std::string::append(std::string const&)", referenced from:
  google_breakpadPFC_::MinidumpGenerator::UniqueNameInDirectory(std::string const&, std::string*) in ParseCrashReporting(minidump_generator.o)
"std::string::append(unsigned long, char)", referenced from:
  google_breakpadPFC_::MinidumpGenerator::UniqueNameInDirectory(std::string const&, std::string*) in ParseCrashReporting(minidump_generator.o)
"std::string::assign(char const*, unsigned long)", referenced from:
  MacStringUtilsPFC_::ConvertToString(__CFString const*) in ParseCrashReporting(string_utilities.o)
"std::string::assign(std::string const&)", referenced from:
  google_breakpadPFC_::ExceptionHandler::ExceptionHandler(std::string const&, bool (*)(void*), bool (*)(char const*, char const*, void*, bool), void*, bool, char const*) in ParseCrashReporting(exception_handler.o)
  google_breakpadPFC_::ExceptionHandler::UpdateNextID() in ParseCrashReporting(exception_handler.o)
  google_breakpadPFC_::MinidumpGenerator::UniqueNameInDirectory(std::string const&, std::string*) in ParseCrashReporting(minidump_generator.o)
  MacStringUtilsPFC_::IntegerValueAtIndex(std::string&, unsigned int) in ParseCrashReporting(string_utilities.o)
  void google_breakpadPFC_::ReadImageInfo<google_breakpadPFC_::MachO64>(google_breakpadPFC_::DynamicImages&, unsigned long long) in ParseCrashReporting(dynamic_images.o)
  void google_breakpadPFC_::ReadImageInfo<google_breakpadPFC_::MachO32>(google_breakpadPFC_::DynamicImages&, unsigned long long) in ParseCrashReporting(dynamic_images.o)
 "std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&)", referenced from:
  BreakpadPFC_::HandleUncaughtException(NSException*) in ParseCrashReporting(Breakpad.o)
  BreakpadPFC_::Initialize(NSDictionary*) in ParseCrashReporting(Breakpad.o)
  BreakpadPFC_::GenerateReport(NSDictionary*) in ParseCrashReporting(Breakpad.o)
  MacStringUtilsPFC_::IntegerValueAtIndex(std::string&, unsigned int) in ParseCrashReporting(string_utilities.o)
  google_breakpadPFC_::ReadTaskString(unsigned int, unsigned long long) in ParseCrashReporting(dynamic_images.o)
  google_breakpadPFC_::UTF16ToUTF8(std::vector<unsigned short, std::allocator<unsigned short> > const&, bool) in ParseCrashReporting(string_conversion.o)
 "std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::string const&)", referenced from:
  google_breakpadPFC_::MinidumpGenerator::UniqueNameInDirectory(std::string const&, std::string*) in ParseCrashReporting(minidump_generator.o)
  google_breakpadPFC_::MinidumpGenerator::WriteModuleStream(unsigned int, MDRawModule*) in ParseCrashReporting(minidump_generator.o)
  void google_breakpadPFC_::ReadImageInfo<google_breakpadPFC_::MachO64>(google_breakpadPFC_::DynamicImages&, unsigned long long) in ParseCrashReporting(dynamic_images.o)
  void google_breakpadPFC_::ReadImageInfo<google_breakpadPFC_::MachO32>(google_breakpadPFC_::DynamicImages&, unsigned long long) in ParseCrashReporting(dynamic_images.o)
  google_breakpadPFC_::DynamicImage::DynamicImage(unsigned char*, unsigned long, unsigned long long, std::string, unsigned long, unsigned int, int) in ParseCrashReporting(dynamic_images.o)
"std::__throw_length_error(char const*)", referenced from:
  std::vector<MDMemoryDescriptor, google_breakpadPFC_::PageStdAllocator<MDMemoryDescriptor> >::reserve(unsigned long) in ParseCrashReporting(minidump_generator.o)
  std::vector<MDMemoryDescriptor, google_breakpadPFC_::PageStdAllocator<MDMemoryDescriptor> >::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<MDMemoryDescriptor*, std::vector<MDMemoryDescriptor, google_breakpadPFC_::PageStdAllocator<MDMemoryDescriptor> > >, MDMemoryDescriptor const&) in ParseCrashReporting(minidump_generator.o)
  std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> >::_M_fill_insert(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<unsigned char*, std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> > >, unsigned long, unsigned char const&) in ParseCrashReporting(dynamic_images.o)
  std::vector<google_breakpadPFC_::DynamicImageRef, std::allocator<google_breakpadPFC_::DynamicImageRef> >::reserve(unsigned long) in ParseCrashReporting(dynamic_images.o)
  std::vector<google_breakpadPFC_::DynamicImageRef, std::allocator<google_breakpadPFC_::DynamicImageRef> >::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<google_breakpadPFC_::DynamicImageRef*, std::vector<google_breakpadPFC_::DynamicImageRef, std::allocator<google_breakpadPFC_::DynamicImageRef> > >, google_breakpadPFC_::DynamicImageRef const&) in ParseCrashReporting(dynamic_images.o)
  std::vector<unsigned short, std::allocator<unsigned short> >::_M_fill_insert(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<unsigned short*, std::vector<unsigned short, std::allocator<unsigned short> > >, unsigned long, unsigned short const&) in ParseCrashReporting(string_conversion.o)
 "std::__throw_out_of_range(char const*)", referenced from:
  google_breakpadPFC_::MinidumpGenerator::UniqueNameInDirectory(std::string const&, std::string*) in ParseCrashReporting(minidump_generator.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

any advice ?

Comment: See this post. you probably have the same error.
[Errors when trying to run the app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15457136/parse-for-ios-errors-when-trying-to-run-the-app)

Answer (score 1):

You didn't add some frameworks or libraries to the project. For instance SLRequest requires social framework.

Comment: You are right. I was importing spare frameworks that I dont need. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem happened because I imported spare frameworks from Parse when I needed to import only `Bolts` and `Parse`