# how do I change app icons/ launch images etc on target build

Tags: ios, xcode

I want to have two build targets for release one for app1 and one for app2 both apps are the same apart from specific customer logo / launch screen etc

I know how to make sure my server side can distinguish between the two apps, (I send a code tag with the app name) but how do I make xcode build two different apps with different logo, launch screen etc

thanks

Comment: Have you tried duplicating the target? What is the specific problem?

Comment: I have two targets and everything work fine apart from the icons, and launch images, where do I change them in the build target ?

Comment: please provide more details

Answer (score 0):

Don't change the target settings. Remove the existing images from the second target. Add a number of new images with the same names as the current icons and default images but in a different folder. Add these new images to the second target. Build and test.

Comment: not sure it is working, when I try to add (drag and drop the new file to the summery tab on the build target on the app Icon) it tells me that a file with that name exist already and do I want to copy it, if I say no nothing happen, if I say yes I get the old file

Comment: Because when you drag it wants the file to be at the top level of the project. If you do that you will need to name the files differently. The aim was to not edit the info.plist, just to switch the files added to the bundle.

Comment: sorry , so how do I do that  if not by dragging the file ?

Comment: You can just name the files differently and drag them in.

Comment: not really working for me, it tells me that I need to name it (with the default name) and ask me to copy it to the higher level with that name

Comment: also it copy the files (after I select or drag / drop) to the top folder, where no file were before, why ? how come it needs to do that, how can I prevent it from copying the files from where they are ?

Comment: Dragging just edits the info.plist. Only the name is placed there, not the path. Add the images to the target as you would with any other image. Ensure the name matches in the plist.

Comment: sound great, as someone who just starting, how do I add the image to the target as any other image ? and it means I need to change the plist right ? where ?

Comment: I probably dont understand the whole concept, here is what I tried, I change the icon files array in the plist (info tab) to match my icon, portrait, and landscape launch images, then selected them one by one on the summary tab, no help it still wanted to copy and rename

Comment: Show the info panel on the right. Select the image on the right. See the target setting on the left with checkboxes. Check the appropriate target.

Comment: sorry Wain this is not helping if Ishow info tab on the right, how do I select images on the right ? the info tab has no images,

Comment: Wain your explanations probably good for someone with more experience I need more details , sorry

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5300785/adding-files-to-seperate-targets-in-xcode-4

Comment: sorry but no, my xcode look different (dont have identity and type, only identity, also this link does not answer my problem at all) - thanks anyway

Comment: anyone else? how do I add a logo to my project to a specific target without causing it to copy it to the main folder ?