# Not Recognizing Function name in AfNetworking

Tags: ios, afnetworking

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:share.profilePicUrl];

  [_imageview setImageWithURLRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url] placeholderImage:

[UIImage imageNamed:@""] success:^(NSURLRequest *request,NSHTTPURLResponse *response,UIImage *image)
         {

             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                    _imageview.image = image;

             });

         } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request,NSHTTPURLResponse *response,NSError *error){

         }];
    });
```

> UIImageView setImageWithURLRequest:placeholderImage:success:failure:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb1b71f0
>
> 2013-12-12 23:41:00.826 Application[6749:1403] *** Terminating app due
>   to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[UIImageView
>   setImageWithURLRequest:placeholderImage:success:failure:]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb1b71f0'

Comment: Are you sure that you have a UIImageView stored in _imageView?

Comment: Could you provide a bit more information on your setup?  Is _imageView an instance of UIImageView, and are you including the UIImageView+AFNetworking category provided by AFNetworking somewhere where _imageView could adopt the setImageWithURLRequest:placeholderImage:success:failure method?

Comment: Did you add AFNetworking as Cocoa Pod or as AFNetworking.framework? In any case, make sure the binaries (.a or .framework) are added in the Copy Phase

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that AFNetworking+UIImageView.m (or more likely, all AFNetworking implementation files) has been added to your target.

Click on AFNetworking+UIImageView.m, and select your target under "Target Membership" in the right window.

See [Adding files to separate targets in Xcode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5300785/adding-files-to-seperate-targets-in-xcode-4)

Comment: If this is the issue, the resolution will be slightly different if you're using Cocoapods to install AFNetworking.

Comment: @AaronBrager I'll bet the 4.17$ in my left pocket he's not using Cocoapods.