# can't get url to work in swift

Tags: swift, avaudioplayer, nsurl, mainbundle

```
var url :NSURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("MTNSoundTrack", ofType: "aif")!)!
```

The name of **my file** and the type are double checked, but still it does not work I'm trying to play a background song in swift `spriteKit`

Comment: With 'double checked' you mean that you opened the Product, showed the package contents and found the file in Contents/Resources?

Comment: Check if the MTNSoundTrack.aif file is added to your app target

Comment: I'm sorry but how do i do so... i can't find the contents/resources folder, so no i have not checked there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the sound was not part of the target so i simply added it

i took this post as a reference:
[Adding files to separate targets in Xcode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5300785/adding-files-to-separate-targets-in-xcode-4)